# passing a string from c++ code to c# dll

Tags: c#, visual-c++

I'm trying to pass a string(image file path) to c# dll interface. I'm getting following runtime error,
"unhandled exception:System.AccessViolationException:Attempt to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.

at System.String.wstrcpy(char* dmem, char* smem, Int32 charCount)

at System.String.CtorCharPtrStartLength(char* ptr, Int32 startIndex, Int32 length)

at System.StubHelpers.BSTRMarshaler.ConvertToManaged(IntPtr bstr)"

C++ code:
Char *img = "filepath";
Typecasting char* into unsigned short* and passing to C# dll interface.

C# dll interface : 
SampleInterface(string str);

Comment: *"Typecasting char into unsigned short*"* .... Errr ... a `char` actually isn't an `unsigned short*` so what are you expecting the typecast to achieve?

Comment: The string in encoded as Unicode or ANSI?

Comment: @Roger Rowland If I don't typecast to unsigned short* compiler will give error.

Comment: @Salvatore how to check string is encoded in Unicode or ANSI ?

Comment: What I really want to do is: I want to pass file path as an argument to c# dll interface from c++.

Comment: @taj you should check the compiler option, btw if  you can modify both sides of codes, take a look here:
http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/184183/Unmanaged-c-to-managed-c-dll-calls-passing-strings

Comment: One important point is: I'm importing c# type library in c++. Code is, #import "<path>.tlb" raw_interfaces_only using namespace <dllnamespace>;

Answer (score 0):

As you are passing string from C++ to C# dll. I would suggest to pass that string as BSTR.

Because these both are different languages.

Comment: Could you please give the sample code snippets, it would be a great help for me.